# Reading data from influxDB in a nodeJS application?

Tags: node.js, influxdb

can you help me with getting data out of an influx DB instance inside a nodeJS application?

I have tried https://github.com/node-influx/node-influx and https://github.com/vicanso/influxdb-nodejs with only little success.

```
const Influx = require('influxdb-nodejs');

//Database connection Influx
const client = new Influx('http://redacted/db');

exports.connectInflux = function () {
var date = new Date();
var timeTo = date.toISOString()
date.setDate(date.getDate() - 4)
var timeFrom = date.toISOString()

var reader = client.query('impulse')
    .where('location', 'SA08')
    .where('time', timeFrom, '>')
    .where('time', timeTo, '<')
     .then(function (data) {
        console.info(data.results[0].series[0].values)
        return data.results[0].series[0].values
    })
    .catch(console.error);

// I get the measurements
client.showMeasurements()
    .then(console.info)
    .catch(console.error)
}
```

With this code snippet, at least I can get the data in the console. But when trying to work with it, I only get an empty array. Can you spot any mistake here?

I am thankful for every hint!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Remember that by default, time must be in nanoseconds. You are using milliseconds.